# Function is returning an incorrect value

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in or not. Even if the user is logged in, it returns the value as false, although it is supposed to return true.

```
  isUserLoggedIn() {
    bool? loggedIn = false;
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print("True is getting executed.");
        loggedIn = true;
      }
    });
    print("Logged In Value: $loggedIn");
    return loggedIn;
  }
```

Shown below is the output for the above code:

```
I/flutter (18584): Logged In Value: false
I/flutter (18584): false
I/flutter (18584): True is getting executed.
```

I'm not sure why the statement `True is getting executed.` is getting printed at last.

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: The order of the log statements should already tell you what you are doing wrong. The inner block is run asynchronously and is only executed way after the method already returned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @luk2302. I'm not sure how to fix it. If you could provide me the solution that should be really great

Comment: I did try applying `async` and `await` but it gives me an warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by @luk2302 said: First you take the block of code that starts with `(User? user)` and ends with `});`, you don't run that, you just hand that over to FirebaseAuth, and ask FirebaseAuth: "Hey, when auth state changes, can you run this code? Thanks!".

Then, immediately after handing that code off, you check the logged in value which is `false`, and some time later, FirebaseAuth runs the code you handed it. This code sets `loggedIn` to `true` which is completely useless as your `isUserLoggedIn` method has long since returned.

To fix it, you need to move the code into the `listen()` block.

Unfortunately, you can't do that here: You can't move the `return` statement into a closure like that.

Thus, we need to widen our view: Whatever code you wrote that is calling `isUserLoggedIn`? That presumable does something with the returned value, for example, it would show a 'login failure' prompt or some such.

*THAT* code needs to be moved into the `listen` block. Which means you want your isUserLoggedIn method to not return anything at all, and instead take as parameter a block of code which you can then execute (either passing it true/false, or probably a better API design, get handed two code blocks, one to run in case login succeeds, and one in case login fails).

This is called 'callback hell'. As the name suggests, it's horrible - you end up writing all methods as returning nothing and taking as parameter a block of code that is to be run once information is available. All your code is an endless chain of code blocks and any attempt to figure out where code is executing is a disaster.

Many languages have solutions to 'callback hell'. [Here is one blog post about using the concept of a future instead](https://medium.com/flutter-community/callback-to-the-future-f9ec0095be2c) - you can find a ton more if you just search the web for 'dart callback hell'.

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborate explanation. This clear a bit on why exactly it wasn't working.